# My ISP gives me an IPv6 Address Range over DHCP, pfSense won't hand it out to the rest of my network

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, pfsense

My ISP gives me a DHCP IPv6 Address /56 range.

I have a friend with the exact same setup as me, and his client PC's/devices all get automatically handed IPv6 addresses.

How it's setup:

pfSense WAN Interface

[image]

[image]

The weird thing is, that my clients get a IPv6 VALID DNS Server, but that's IT. No address of any kind except link local.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem. Turns out the ISP offers two lengths of IPv6 ranges. I corrected mine to the appropriate size and the problem went away :)